# Postback using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How to cause a postback using javascript in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script language='Javascript'>
__doPostBack('__Page', 'MyCustomArgument');
</script>
```

or if you just strictly want a postback you can send a null argument

```
<script language='Javascript'>
__doPostBack('__Page', '');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacobnlsn is correct.  However, if you want to do custom *handling* of the postback on the page as well, take a look at the IPostbackEventHandler interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx